# SSL3_GET_RECORD Error Using Delphi XE5 RestClient

Tags: rest, delphi, https

First time trying to connect to a server's HTTP API Interface using RESTClient/1.0 library installed with Delphi XE5. `RestRequest.Execute` raises an EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError Exception:

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines: SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
```

Only components used are RestClient, RestRequest, and RestResponse.

**from the .dfm file**:

```
  object RESTClient1: TRESTClient
    Accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    BaseURL = 'https://intakeq.com/api/v1'
    ContentType = 'ctAPPLICATION_JSON'
    Params = <>
    HandleRedirects = True
    Left = 117
    Top = 256
  end
  object RESTRequest: TRESTRequest
    Client = RESTClient1
    Params = <>
    Response = RESTResponse1
    Left = 185
    Top = 258
  end
```

from the .pas file

```
  RestRequest.Params.Clear;
  RestClient1.BaseURL := sBaseUrl + 'practitioners';
  RestRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
  RestRequest.Params.AddItem;
  RestRequest.Params[0].Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
  RestRequest.Params[0].name := 'X-Auth-Key';
  RestRequest.Params[0].Value := 'xxxxxyyyyyzzzzz';
```

When I put the same information into the Embarcadero REST Debugger it connected without an error.

Is there an updated REST Client Library that would work with XE5, and if so, where would I find it?
I don't see anything in the TRestClient or TRestResponse components that indicates what the SSL or TLS version is. Is that something that I need to install separately?

Comment: `EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError` is an Indy exception type. Early versions of Embarcadero's REST tech did use Indy, but XE5 is old, as is the version of Indy it shipped with. It likely it not compatible with modern TLS requirements (in particular, TLS 1.2 and it's SNI extension). Embarcadero's REST tech no longer uses Indy, but if upgrading to a modern Delphi version is not an option, then I would suggest switching to Indy's `TIdHTTP` directly, and then installing an up-to-date version of Indy from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy).